# JQuery copying select box selected value from one select box to another

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-selectors

I have 3 select box, and I would like to copy the selected value to the 2nd select box and from the 2nd box to the third select box. The select box will have the same options through out the 3 select box.

How would I go about this?

JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/andrewvmail/27rFQ/3/

```
 A:<select id="inputsa">
    <option id="inputa"  name="input[1][]">A</option>
    <option id="inputb" name="input"> B</option>
    <option id="inputc"  name="input[2][]"> C</option>
</select> 
B:<select id="inputsb">
    <option id="inputa"  name="input[1][]">A</option>
    <option id="inputb" name="input"> B</option>
    <option id="inputc"  name="input[2][]"> C</option>
</select> 
C:<select id="inputsc">
    <option id="inputa"  name="input[1][]">A</option>
    <option id="inputb" name="input">B</option>
    <option id="inputc"  name="input[2][]">C</option>
</select> 

<br>    




    <input id="copyAtoB" type="button" value="Copy A to B" onclick="functionCopyAtoB();">
        <br>
    <input id="copyBtoC" type="button" value="Copy B to C" onclick="functionCopyBtoC();">
```

Cheers

Comment: You mean If you select `B` in select box A, it should be pasted into select box B and it has four options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function functionCopyAtoB() {
    $('#inputsb').val($('#inputsa').val());
}
function functionCopyBtoC() {
    $('#inputsc').val($('#inputsb').val());
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/27rFQ/44/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use this...

```
$(':button').on('click', function(){
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'copyAtoB'){
        $('#inputsb').val($('#inputsa').val());
        $('#inputsb').attr('selected', true);
    }else if($(this).attr('id') == 'copyBtoC'){
        $('#inputsc').val($('#inputsb').val());
        $('#inputsc').attr('selected', true);
    }
});
```

And see this [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/27rFQ/17/)

Answer (score 0):

Please note that *all* following examples are based on corrected HTML (an `<option>` tag is closed with `</option>`, and ***not***, as you seem to think, an `</input>` tag, *no* element is closed with an `</input>` tag):

```
A:
<select id="inputsa">
    <option id="inputa" name="input[1][]">A</option>
    <option id="inputb" name="input">B</option>
    <option id="inputc" name="input[2][]">C</option>
</select>B:
<select id="inputsb">
    <option id="inputa" name="input[1][]">A</option>
    <option id="inputb" name="input">B</option>
    <option id="inputc" name="input[2][]">C</option>
</select>C:
<select id="inputsc">
    <option id="inputa" name="input[1][]">A</option>
    <option id="inputb" name="input">B</option>
    <option id="inputc" name="input[2][]">C</option>
</select>
<br>
<input id="copyAtoB" type="button" value="Copy A to B" data-from="a" data-to="b">
<br>
<input id="copyBtoC" type="button" value="Copy B to C" data-from="b" data-to="c">
```

One approach:

```
function copyValue(from,to){
    /* these lines check if the supplied variables are Objects, with a
       typeof check, if they *are* they're assumed to be jQuery objects
       and that object is retained in the variable; otherwise it's assumed
       to be the String of an id, and a jQuery object is created, and
       assigned to the variable. */
    from = typeof from == "object" ? from : $('#' + from);
    to = typeof to == "object" ? to : $('#' + to);

    // gets the selected option, and copies that to the other node/object
    to[0].selectedIndex = from[0].selectedIndex;
}

$('#copyAtoB').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    copyValue($('#inputsa'),$('#inputsb'));
});

$('#copyBtoC').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    copyValue($('#inputsb'),$('#inputsc'));
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewvmail/27rFQ/22/).

A tidied-up, slightly more generic jQuery option:

```
function copyValue(from, to) {
    // same as above
    from = typeof from == "object" ? from : $('#' + from);
    to = typeof to == "object" ? to : $('#' + to);
    to[0].selectedIndex = from[0].selectedIndex;
}

$('input:button').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // retrieves the data from the current jQuery object
    var data = $(this).data(),
        // gets the 'from' data (where you're copying from)
        f = 'inputs' + data.from,
        // gets the 'to' data (where you're copying to)
        t = 'inputs' + data.to;
    /* calls the function, demonstrating passing both a jQuery object,
       and a String equal to the relevant id */
    copyValue($('#' + f), t);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewvmail/27rFQ/21/).

And just because I quite like plain JavaScript:

```
function copyValue(from,to, prefix){
    // sets a default prefix to be used
    prefix = prefix || 'inputs';
    /* checks if the variables are element nodes, if they are that node
       is used. Otherwise we assume an id is passed, and use that to find
       the relevant element node */
    from = from.nodeType == 1 ? from : document.getElementById(prefix + from);
    to = to.nodeType == 1 ? to : document.getElementById(prefix + to);
    to.selectedIndex = from.selectedIndex;
}

// gets all input elements
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

// iterates through those input elements, and...
for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i<len; i++){
    // if they have a type equal to 'button'...
    if (inputs[i].type == 'button') {
        // binds a click-handler
        inputs[i].onclick = function(e){

            // gets the values from 'data-from' and 'data-to' attributes
            var f = this.getAttribute('data-from'),
                t = this.getAttribute('data-to');
            // assigns the function to be called, with the arguments
            copyValue(f,t, 'inputs');
        };
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewvmail/27rFQ/20/).

References:

- jQuery, from the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/):

  - [`:button` selector](http://api.jquery.com/button-selector/).
  - [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
  - [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).
  - [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).
  - [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- Plain JavaScript, from the [Mozilla Developer Network's JavaScript resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript):

  - [`Element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.getAttribute).
  - [`Node.nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeType).
  - [Conditional/ternary operator: `condition ? true : false`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
  - [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#copyAtoB").click(function() {

   var o = new Option($('#inputsa :selected').text(), "value");

   $(o).html($('#inputsa :selected').text());
   $("#inputsb").append(o);
 });   


 $("#copyBtoC").click(function() {

   var o = new Option($('#inputsb :selected').text(), "value");
  $(o).html($('#inputsb :selected').text());
  $("#inputsc").append(o);
 });
```

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/27rFQ/18/)